# Column that must be unique only for rows with matching foreign key

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to enforce a uniqueness constraint on a table and I'm not sure the best way to go about it. I have two tables: `Parent` and `Child`. `Child.parent_id` is a foreign key referencing `Parent.id`. I would like for `Child.name` values to be unique, but only for members of `Child` where the `Child.parent_id` value is the same. That is,

1. `child_one.parent_id == child_two.parent_id && child_one.name == child_two.name` should be **impossible**
2. `child_one.parent_id != child_two.parent_id && child_one.name == child_two.name` should be **possible**.

If it's a great deal of trouble I may be willing to relax the second constraint and simply say that `Child.name` must simply be globally unique, but I'm not very experienced with databases so I thought I would ask for advice.

I'm writing the application using Laravel, so the exact database technology is more of an implementation detail, but we happen to be using MySQL.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is there any reason a UNIQUE NON-CLUSTERED index on those two columns wouldn't work?

Comment: @Akina that's exactly what I was looking for! I knew this was the perfect question for a StackExchange site. Something relatively simple for someone with experience, but difficult to google for if you don't know the right words! Care to write up an answer?

Comment: No problems... moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like for `Child.name` to be unique, but only for members of Child where `Child.parent_id` is the same.

This mean you need NOT `(Child.name)` to be unique. 
You need in `(Child.name, Child.parent_id)` to be unique.